# Compiling VB6 Code on all files automatically

Tags: vb6

I wanted help regarding VB6 Code. We use different SCADA softwares like iFIX by GE or Vijeo citect by Schneider.
Basically the front view of the different files made by these softwares is graphic and the back end is respective code of the graphic in VB6 format.

There are thousand of graphics which have very huge amount of vb6 code in their back end. What i wanted to know how can i compile all those codes automatically. Using VB6 software by Microsoft i can access / Open the graphics in their respective application.

i also can go in their script but i dont know how can i compile the code after that automatically. Could any one shed some light.

If anyone has any idead regarding the same please reply.

Thanks & Regards

PTD

Comment: Use Cruise Control. Create an ANT script that builds your VB6 projects.

Comment: Please explain "front view of the different viles made by these softwares is graphic and the back end is respective code of the graphic in VB6 format.". And how can graphics have huget amount of VB6 code in their back end? Most people would expect "graphics" to refer to bitmap - or more specifically, bitmap files.

Comment: Please give me some time to show you the graphics. generally these are bitmaps but most of the bitmaps have different click events or timed events. a group of around 200-300 objects create a graphic for which most of them have click events. Ill post the demo tomorrow. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

We Compile in a normal Batch File:

For DLL and OCX:
"C:\programme\microsoft visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe" /makedll "C:\SourceCode\Controls\Education\Education.vbp"

For Executables
"C:\programme\microsoft visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe" /make "C:\C4SourceCode\Programs\Consolidate\Concolidate.vbp"

Is this what you are Looking for?